# Slope detection in 2D platformers

Tags: physics, mathematics

I am currently shifting from unity to monogame to make 2d platformers. I am not aware of any sort of "raycasting" provided with monogame, I am aware of AABB collision detection and I am planning to implement it.

I was wondering how do I deal with slope detection. Making a level without slope would make it look very bland to my liking and I want to some slopes in it. Is there any way to achieve slope detection?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you considered incorporating a physics library that gives you raycasting and other detection support, like Box2D?

Comment: I have thought about it, but I want to try to do it myself, as a learning experience. I know it's sort of like re-inventing the wheel, but still, I want to do it myself.

Comment: So then you looked up tutorials on building the physics engine features you need?